# how to get data from updated table row after setting value to the specific td using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

After a successful form submission I update the datatable row values with new values using jQuery. That part is shown below.

```
//////////////Form Submision//////////////
$('#btnSaveCallRegisterTable').click(function () {
if (confirm('Do you want to ' + formAction + ' data ?', 'YES', 'No')) {
                    $.CCAjax("/Service/SaveServiceCall", form.serializeArray(),
                        function (data) {
                            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log(jsonData);
                            if (jsonData["Response_Code"] === 200 || jsonData["Response_Code"] === "200") {
 $('#thisDivSuccessAlert').html('<div id="divAlert" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><b><i class="icon fas fa-check"></i>' + jsonData.Response_Message + '. Please note the reference number : ' + jsonData.Call_Id + ' for future reference. </b></div>');
                                    console.log(jsonData);
                                    var slctdIndex = idx + 1;
                                    var Call_details = $('#Call_Details').val();
                                    var Contact_No = $('#Contact_No').val();
                                    var Requested_By = $('#Requested_By').val();
                                    var Call_Type = $('#Call_Type_Id1 option:selected').text();
                                    var Product = $('#Product_Id1 option:selected').text();
                                    $('table tr:nth-child(' + slctdIndex + ')').find('td:nth-child(4)').text(Product)
                                    $('table tr:nth-child(' + slctdIndex + ')').find('td:nth-child(5)').text(Call_Type)
                                    $('table tr:nth-child(' + slctdIndex + ')').find('td:nth-child(6)').text(Call_details)
                                    $('table tr:nth-child(' + slctdIndex + ')').find('td:nth-child(7)').text(Requested_By)
                                    $('table tr:nth-child(' + slctdIndex + ')').find('td:nth-child(8)').text(Contact_No)
}
 });
```

After that the  `td` value is updated with the new value.

Then I select the row for editing I get the previous row data values but I want updated row values

```
///Edit  the table row/////

 $('#btnEditCallRegisterTable').click(function () {
 var rowToUpdate = [];
            if ($('#CallRegisterTable tr.selected').length !== 1) {
                
                    alert("Please Select One Row To Edit!!!");
                    return false;
            }

            var index = $.SetRowId();
            var datatable = $("#CallRegisterTable").DataTable();
            //Row to Edit
            var EditRow = datatable.cells({ row: index, column: 0 }).data()[0];
           // console.log(EditRow);
  var jsonObjectUpdateData = {};
            $.each(EditRow, function (key, value) {
                jsonObjectUpdateData[key] = value;
            });
            jsonObjectUpdateData["Data_Status"] = 'U';
            rowToUpdate.push(jsonObjectUpdateData);
            $.CCAjax("/Service/CallRegisterEditForm", { requestData: jsonObjectUpdateData },
                function (data) {
                    $(".call-register-form").html(data);
                }
            );


});
```

//CCAjax is a customized ajax call.
//$.SetRowId() is the selected row index.

```
//controller action
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CallRegisterEditForm(ServiceCallRequestModel requestData)
{
   return CCPartialView("_CallRegisterEditForm", requestData);
}
```

after successful form submission table row data changed after that again i selected the same row in that table ,my form rendered with old table row data but i need updated row data values .Can anyone guide me to achieve it.

Comment: Please post [mre] so we can see for ourselves and limit the guessing. But from the first look at it you are changing the inner text with `.text()` and later fetching the HTML data attribute with `.data()[`, those two things are not the same. Check you DEV tools on dose elements. You need to use ether `text()` in both cases or set and read data attributes in both with `.data()`. Please read documentation on what you are using. https://api.jquery.com/data/ https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: You're only updating the rendered HTML, you're not amending the underlying data which datatables uses to render the table. Try this:https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36957/how-to-update-existing-row

Comment: i added jquery coeds in cshtml for more clarification. i need changed td values. how i get the updated values.

Comment: can you help me to find out a solution

Comment: Have you tried @RoryMcCrossan advice? I really think that's the proper solution to your problem.

Comment: i used row().invalidate() .but updated values do not affect the table.

Comment: i select a row in table for edit. that values placed into the inputs at the form. After successful submission, table row changed with updated values in form. Again I fetch the same row and placed into corresponding form input field but form input field shows the previous td vales before first update.